# How to make two criteria if any one of them fulfill code will autofilter it?

Tags: vba, excel, filter

[image]

The code is working fine for a single criterion. I want to make it work based on two criteria with an OR condition. If any one condition is met, it would auto filter the data.

```
Sub FilterCopyToOtherSheet()
'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C7").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E2"), _
        CopyToRange:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), _
        Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: In order to get an or condition i think you need to run the filter copy iteratively, as autofilter assumes an AND relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the advanced filter criterions in the same row are `AND` connected however criterions in different rows are `OR` connected.

So in this example in Sheet1

[image]

the criterion range reads like:

Filter if

```
Like = Yes AND Color <> Green AND Color <> Red
OR 
Like = No AND Color = Green
OR
Like = No AND Color = Brown
```

So with

```
Sub FilterCopyToOtherSheet()

 With ThisWorkbook

  Set oWS1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set oWS2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")

  oWS2.Cells.ClearContents

  lLastRowTable = oWS1.Cells(oWS1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  lLastRowCrit = oWS1.Cells(oWS1.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

    oWS1.Range("A1:C" & lLastRowTable).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=oWS1.Range("E1:G" & lLastRowCrit), _
        CopyToRange:=oWS2.Range("A1"), _
        Unique:=False

 End With

End Sub
```

it leads to

[image]

in Sheet2.